# Join all link table entries in one single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to get a query which would allow me to put all music genres of an event (Link table) in a single row but I have been quite unsuccessful so far; it constantly returns 2 rows with the same information about the event in each but changing the music genre entries at the LEFT JOIN. Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    events.*
    , music_genres_link.* 
FROM events 
LEFT JOIN music_genres_link 
    ON events.id = music_genres_link.event_id 
WHERE events.id=1 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

And here's what it returns:

[image: Phpmyadmin Screenshot]

How do I get these two rows together in a single one? I need both the genre_title and genre_id columns.

I'd like to get the whole event row and left join all the music genres found on the link table to the left of the result, as such:

[event result] [music_genre_1 (id, title)] [music_genre_2 (id, title)] etc

Comment: share your sample data and expected result set?

Comment: This is not a complete question.  Please include sample data for both of the original tables.  We can't really decompose your result set link (don't post links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you just want `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT e.*, GROUP_CONCAT(mgl.genre_title) as genres
FROM events e LEFT JOIN
     music_genres_link mgl
     ON e.id = mgl.event_id 
WHERE e.id = 1 
GROUP BY e.id;
```

This assumes that you want the `genre_title` only.  If you want the `genre_id`, then you can add another column.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have 2 rows that match the join in `music_genres_link`. You can see that from the two 'gender_id' values - 5 and 295.

Ok now that you have edited your question, you want something that is not typical for SQL. You can achieve that with [PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) but you dont have limit for the amount of genres and i wouldn't recommend it. You need to rethink your tables and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Indeed, I do. But how do I get them in a single row?

Comment: Whell one way is to choose the one you want and to add it in the `where` or `join` clause

Comment: Dimo raichev is absolutely right - you have to define first: how should they be combined in one row? You want to keep one row and get rid of the other one? You want to get them combined via comma-seperated value lists? There are multiple possibilities ...

Comment: @IuriDias your data doesn't seem consistent why do you have 2 gender types with different IDs and same names

Comment: @dimoraichev It's a reference to a JSON file I have on the server.

Comment: @Grimm It doesn't really matter, I simply want all the results found on the music_genres_link table to output to a single row, be it comma seperated or not.